# Can I run webpage's JavaScript function in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

When I hover over an image in a webpage it shows a JavaScript function in the status bar `javascript:main.somefunction("arg1","arg2","arg3")`. Is it possible to run that function in the context of the webpage and render the results with PhantomJS?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an element such as

```
<a href='javascript:main.somefunction("arg1","arg2","arg3")'>
    <img src='someImage.jpg'>
</a>
```

then you should see the URI of the link in the status bar. Since the page has to know about the `main` object in order to call the function on it, `main` has to be an object in the global scope (on the `window` object). You can either call `main.somefunction("arg1","arg2","arg3")` or `window.main.somefunction("arg1","arg2","arg3")` in the page context.

If the function changes the page asynchronously, then you have to wait for the change. A static delay can be done with `setTimeout()`. If you need to wait for a specific condition, then you can use the [`waitFor()` function from the examples directory](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js).

```
page.open(url, function(status){
    if (status === "fail") {
        console.log("Load failed");
        phantom.exit(1);
        return;
    }

    page.evaluate(function(){
        main.somefunction("arg1","arg2","arg3")
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render("screenshot.png");
        phantom.exit();
    }, 3000); // 3 seconds delay
});
```

Comment: Now I get an error TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'main.somefunction("arg1", "arg2",  "arg3")')